# Extracting zipped files using JSZIP in javascript not working on IE11

Tags: angularjs, jszip

In my webpage, a user is supposed to upload a zipped file. Within the zipped file are multiple xlsx files. I am using below code for reading ZIP file , It works great on Chrome but when I am trying to run on IE11 it says, could not find resolve for null object or reference

```
    var JSZip = require('JSZip');
fs.readFile{ filePath, function(err, data) {
  if (!err) {
    var zip = new JSZip();
    zip.loadAsync(data).then(function(contents) {
      Object.keys(contents.files).forEach(function(filename) {
        zip.file(filename).async('nodebuffer').then(function(content) {
           var dest = path + filename;
           fs.writeFileSync(dest, content);
        }); 
      });
    });
  }
});
```

When I try to debug it is not going inside loadAync function.

Comment: You appear to be using this in NodeJS (from the use of `fs.readFile` and the use of the `nodejs-jszip` tag), but you've also tagged this `angularjs`. It's a bit unclear where this code is running. Please do tell us the exact error and which line the error is occurring at. Note that the code, as is, will not run on any browser, since `fs` is not defined.

Comment: This is simple angular js code..not node js code.. This is just sample code I have written I am just trying to do extract and read zip file content in angular js using JSZip librarary

Comment: This is simple angular js code..not node js code.. This is just sample code I have written I am just trying to do extract and read zip file content in angular js using JSZip librarary